I need help identifying this component
Help needed to identify this component:


I found this which looks similar, but am unsure: Need help identifying a part
When I google capacitor, I find a covered component (I am unsure what is underneath.)


The component is an inductor. The text on it is so poorly visible that it's unknown if it reads "121" for 120 uH or something else. However, all other parameters such as rated current or DC resistance of the inductor will remain unknown and it cannot be identified further to e.g. buy a matching part.

If you measure the diameter of the wire, you can estimate the thermal current limit. If you count the turns as you unwind it and measure the diameter of the core, you can estimate the saturation current.

It's an low-end unshielded inductor (probably a power inductor) with what looks like a broken ferrite bobbin. You might be able to figure out the proper value by looking at the datasheet for whatever IC it might have been connected to. Or not.

I read 471 on the picture, which would be 470 µH.
